# TypeScript bug, or not? Declaration only works when written in certain formats

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

In a `.d.ts` declaration file, I tried to do the same thing in four different ways, but only two of them work:

```
// Doesn't work.
declare global {
    const THREE: typeof import('three')
}

// Doesn't work.
import * as _THREE from 'three'
declare const THREE: typeof _THREE

// Works.
import * as _THREE from 'three'
declare global {
    const THREE: typeof _THREE
}

// Works.
declare const THREE: typeof import('three')
```

The `'three'` module contains `export namespace THREE`.

In the first two cases, other `.ts` files using `THREE` as a global will have the error `'THREE' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.`

With the two cases that do work, other `.ts` files using the `THREE` global do not have such an error, and they use my definition of `THREE` as expected.

f.e., if I use the second non-working option in a `.d.ts` file:

```
// globals.d.ts
import * as _THREE from 'three'
declare const THREE: typeof _THREE
```

then in another `.ts` file:

```
// other-file.ts
console.log(THREE) // ERROR: 'THREE' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

But if I use the fourth (last) option,

```
// globals.d.ts
declare const THREE: typeof import('three')
```

then there's no problem in the other file:

```
// other-file.ts
console.log(THREE) // no problem.
```

Why do the first two options not work, but the last two do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have such kind of issue.  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58261279/how-to-declare-reference-to-an-existing-namespace-which-is-available-from-javacr/)

With your **tsconfig.json** you could use:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,
```

It gives compiler access to UMD globals, THREE types is listed. So you do not need to import or reference it after. Same like JQuery or $.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, let me say that given this error: `'THREE' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.`, you might actually be interested in the new compiler option `allowUmdGlobalAccess` in 3.5 [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30776) (although I see you commented on the associated [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10178), making sure you didn't miss the fix).

Regarding the errors, this is just an intersection of how global augmentation works and what is and isn't a module:

1. `global` can only be used in modules, `global` is not necessary in script files
2. A file is a module if it contains an `import` or `export` statement otherwise it is considered a script file.

Given these 2 binary rules, we get the exact 4 possibilities you describe

**1. Not a module, with `global` => error.**

```
declare global {
    const THREE: typeof import('three')
}
```

Since the file is not a module but a simple script file, using `global` is an error, since anything declared in this file would be in the global namespace anyway, so why add `global` ?

**2. Module, without `global`  => unused module constant**

```
    import * as _THREE from 'three'
    declare const THREE: typeof _THREE
```

Since this file contains an `import` it is a module, so the declared const is not in any way in the global scope and thus it's just a module local variable that will go unused. The error you are getting in other files is from the `three` module itself (which declares a UMD global namespace)

**3. Module, with global**

```
import * as _THREE from 'three'
declare global {
    const THREE: typeof _THREE
}
```

In this case the file is a module, but the definition is in a `global` augmentation. This mean that the definition of `THREE` will be put in the global namespace and will be available in other files

**4. Not a module, no global**

```
declare const THREE: typeof import('three')
```

In this last case, the file is not a module in spite of the import type. Only import statements make the file a module, import types do not. Since this file is not a module the `THREE` constant declared is in the global namespace and available as such in other files.

Comment: I'm not getting any "error", the two of them just silently fail. Is that expected?